# C# pointer with offset and vaMemory.dll

Tags: c#, pointers, offset

So I want to try to read a value from memory using a pointer with 1 offset.

These are my value:

[image: cheatengine]

I tried to write some code but it does not work. It only ever reads value 0 but I see on cheat engine the value `i` is different.

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
namespace Trigger
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            VAMemory vam = new VAMemory("test");
            int LocalPlayer = vam.ReadInt32((IntPtr)0x01608310);        
            while (true) {
                int address = LocalPlayer + 0x360;
                Console.Write(vam.ReadInt32((IntPtr)address));
                //Thread.sleep(500);                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So can someone help me to understand?

Comment: Should be : Console.Write(vam.ReadInt32((IntPtr)(LocalPlayer + address)));

Comment: Don't work bro.